# JS - input type radio gets unselected when user clicks Cancel in the onclick='return confirm('msg')';

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

**EDIT:**

Apparently it only happens in IE. This snippet ilustrates the issue:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <SPAN id=selectOperacion class=x2j>
            <INPUT onclick="return confirm('probando');" type=radio name=selectOperacion id=selectOperacion:_0>
            <LABEL title=Préstamo for=selectOperacion:_0>Préstamo</LABEL>

            <INPUT onclick="return confirm('probando');" type=radio name=selectOperacion id=selectOperacion:_1>
            <LABEL title="Traspaso de material" for=selectOperacion:_1>Traspaso de material</LABEL></SPAN>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Old post:**

I have two radio buttons defined using Apache Trinidad like this:

```
<tr:selectOneRadio id="selectOperacion" 
    value="#{myBean.operacion}" 
    autoSubmit="true" 
    valueChangeListener="#{myBean.myChangeListener}"
    onclick="return confirm('test');" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.options}" />
</tr:selectOneRadio>
```

This generates two input elements with type radio.

The issue is that when user clicks the option "Cancel" in the confirm dialog the both of the radio buttons get unselected.

Is there any way to keep the selected state of the radio button when confirm() return false?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is when you're selecting any radio, onClick will be fired, so what will happen now is if you press ok then it will return true and will select radio but when you press cancel it will return false it won't select that radio. so maybe you need to change the event you are using to do your work. Hope this helps :)

Comment: It's not an event issue. In my edit I explain that this strange behaviour only happens in IE so I suspect a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an IE bug.

I solved my issue by saving the previous state of the radio buttons into variables in the onmousedown event.
Then in the onclick event I call a function that launches the confirm dialog and if the user clicks cancel then I restore the state of the radio buttons.

```
onmousedown="update_state();"
onclick="return updateRadios(this);"

<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
    var prev_radio0_state;
    var prev_radio1_state;

    // param es el radiobutton que se ha pulsado
    function updateRadios(param) { 
        var radio0 = document.getElementById("selectOperacion:_0");
        var radio1 = document.getElementById("selectOperacion:_1");

        if (radio0 == null || radio1 == null) {
            // si solo hay un radio button no hay que hacer nada
            return false;
        }

        if (param == radio0 && prev_radio0_state == true 
            || param == radio1 && prev_radio1_state == true) {
                // se ha pulsado un boton que ya estaba seleccionado por lo
                // que no hay que hacer nada
                return false;
        }

        // aqui sabemos que existen los dos radio buttons y que se ha pulsado
        // el que no estaba ya seleccionado

        var ok = confirm('seguro?');

        if (ok) {
            return true;
        }

        radio0.checked = prev_radio0_state;
        radio1.checked = prev_radio1_state;

        return false;
    }

    // Guarda el estado checked de los radiobutton antes de cambiarlo en el evento click.
    // Se llama en el evento onmousedown
    function update_state() {
        var radio0 = document.getElementById("selectOperacion:_0");
        var radio1 = document.getElementById("selectOperacion:_1");

        if (radio0 != null) {
            prev_radio0_state = radio0.checked;
        } else {
            prev_radio0_state = null;
        }

        if (radio1 != null) {
            prev_radio1_state = radio1.checked;
        } else {
            prev_radio1_state = null;
        }
    }
//]]>
</script>
```